# How to remove the Powered by Odoo #1 Open Source eCommerce footer from front end of Odoo 8?

Tags: javascript, python, odoo, openerp-8, qweb

How do you remove the backlinks from the public front end of Odoo 8?

Location: lower right corner of the page, in the footer.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="pull-right">
     Powered by <a class="label label-danger" href="http://www.odoo.com/page/website-builder">Odoo</a>,
     the #1 
     <a href="http://www.odoo.com/page/e-commerce">Open Source eCommerce</a>.
</div>
```

These backlinks are shown to all search engines, and to anybody visiting the site, who is not logged in to the site!!

And when you log in, Odoo dynamically removes the links from the generated HTML page.

Odoo is very nice, but...

We cannot be displaying its back links on all public website page footers!

How do you remove them??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've determined how to solve this issue.

1. First, log in to back end as administrator. Activate Technical Features, if not already activated, by going to Settings > Users > Users > (your Administrator user name, default is Administrator) > Edit > Usability > Technical Features > check the box (active), click Save.
2. Go to Settings > Technical > User Interface > Views.
3. In the search box, next to "(filter icon) Active", type "Footer Copyright", and hit enter to search.
4. There will be one search result. (View name: Footer Copyright. View type: QWeb view.) Click to open it.
5. Click Edit.
6. Comment out lines 6-7 of the code as follows:
   `<!-- Powered by <a class="label label-danger" href="http://www.odoo.com/page/website-builder">Odoo</a>,
   the #1 <a href="http://www.odoo.com/page/e-commerce">Open Source eCommerce</a>. -->`
7. Click Save.
8. Refresh the browser view of your Odoo front end website.  Log out of the front end of your Odoo website.  You'll see the previously visible "Powered by" backlinks and text, is now removed!
   For more info or help, see the following blog entry:
   http://www.espacenetworks.com/blog/entry/how-to-remove-the-powered-by-odoo-1-open-source-ecommerce-footer-from-front-end-of-odoo-8.html

Answer (score 2):

It's recommended to use modules to make updates in odoo.

You can create new module or try existed modules, e.g. [website_debranding](https://github.com/yelizariev/website-addons/tree/8.0/website_debranding):

```
<template id="layout_footer_copyright" inherit_id="website.layout_footer_copyright">
    <xpath expr="//div[@t-ignore='true']" position="replace">
    </xpath>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove it directly from the source code (or modify to anything you want. Take a look at the file `openerp/addons/website/views/website_templates.xml`

P/s: Sorry for not posting this as a comment as it requires me 50 reputations :(

Comment: No problem not posting as a comment - I've got the same restriction.  Had a look inside that file

Comment: The HTML backlinks are not in there. They're different ones. Looks like it might be a previous version of the footer?
    Create a <a href="http://www.odoo.com/page/website-builder">free website</a> with
    <a href="http://www.odoo.com/page/website-builder">Odoo</a>

Answer (score 0):

See this guide: http://odoo.guide/debranding-odoo-backend/

There is a module to override all of that, which is the preferred way.

Check the master branch here https://superuser.com/a/808851/71031

Answer (score 0):

1. Active developer mode.
2. Enable technical features.
3. Go to `Settings > Technical > User Interface > Views`.
4. In the search box, next to `(filter icon) Active`, type `secondary`, and hit enter to search.
5. Choose `web.menu_secondary`. Click to open it.
6. Now find this tag  and comment it like.

   ```
   <!--div class="oe_footer">
     Powered by <a href="http://www.openerp.com" target="_blank"><span>Odoo</span></a>
   </div-->
   ```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It work for me in odoo13

````
<odoo>

    <data >
        <template id="layout_footer_copyright" inherit_id="website.layout">
            <xpath expr="//div[hasclass('o_footer_copyright')]" position="replace">

            </xpath>
        </template>
    </data>

</odoo> ```
````